# Understanding ask pattern in akka

Tags: scala, akka

I'm trying to use ask pattern in akka. As far as I read from the [documentation](http://doc.akka.io/docs/akka/snapshot/scala/actors.html):

> **The ask operation involves creating an internal actor for handling**
>   **this reply**, which needs to have a timeout after which it is destroyed
>   in order not to leak resources; see more below.

The question is I want to reply the sender when the future is completed succesfully:

```
 trait Command
 trait Status
 case class SetStatus(c: Command, st: Status)+
 sealed trait StatusChangeResponse
 object Ok extends StatusChangeResponse
 //...
 override def receive: Receive = {
    case c : Command => {
      val f = sender ? SetStatus(c, Run) map(v => v.asInstanceOf[StatusChangeResponse])
      f.onComplete{
        case Success(Ok) =>
          c()
          sender ! SetStatus(c, Finished) // <---- Here
      }
    }
  }
```

The issue is I don't quite understand if it's okay to do like that. As specified in the documentation it's executed in another actor. So `sender` maybe not what I would expected.

Is it okay to do like that?

Comment: @YuvalItzchakov What does it mean closing over mutable state?

Comment: You're closing over `sender`, meaning you're creating a function which has to carry a reference to `sender` even after `receive` exits and it doesn't point to what you think it does when `onComplete` is called. This is called [closure](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Closure_(computer_programming)).

Comment: @YuvalItzchakov Thankx much

Comment: @YuvalItzchakov But what about stopping the actor liek `context stop self` inside the callbacks? I think it's ok since it is a `val`.

Comment: What is `self` when the callback is called? You're no longer in actor context.

Comment: @YuvalItzchakov It means I have to introduce another local `val` to do so?

Comment: I'm actually not sure about `self` here. Give it a test.